# When I insert a Linear Layout I get 'The application has stopped unexpectedly' error

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I am an android newbie, started learning recently.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bugaman.android.inspireme.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/inspire" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/finalshake" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Inspire Me!"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="2.0"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this code, everything is fine, But when I insert a Linear layout, I get the error for the following code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bugaman.android.inspireme.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/inspire" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.77"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="2.0"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.115"
            android:text="Inspire Me!"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.115"
            android:src="@drawable/finalshake" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here what I did is,
Insert LinearLayout(vertical)...
fill height...
center horizontally...
dragged the textview1, button1 and imageview1 into LinearLayout...
changed the weightsum of linear layout to 1...
weight of textview1 to 0.77...
weight of button1 to 0.115...
weight of imageview1 to 0.115...
changed the layout height of textview1, button1, and imageview1 to 0dp...
Now if I run, I get the error 'The application blah blah has stopped unexpectedly.'...

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Logcat Messages --

```
06-19 12:55:34.409: D/AndroidRuntime(7999): Shutting down VM
06-19 12:55:34.419: W/dalvikvm(7999): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401b9648)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bugaman.android.inspireme/com.bugaman.android.inspireme.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at com.bugaman.android.inspireme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
06-19 12:55:34.429: E/AndroidRuntime(7999):     ... 11 more
06-19 13:03:33.717: D/AndroidRuntime(9096): Shutting down VM
06-19 13:03:33.717: W/dalvikvm(9096): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401b9648)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bugaman.android.inspireme/com.bugaman.android.inspireme.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at com.bugaman.android.inspireme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
06-19 13:03:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(9096):     ... 11 more
06-19 13:08:33.820: D/Process(9096): killProcess, pid=9096
```

Comment: you can do better than "The application blah blah".. Post the proper error message

Comment: 'The application Inspire me! has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.'

Comment: lol, share your logcat logs ! ! !

Comment: @SercanOzdemir I am a new guy to this whole thing, i dont know how to show u my logcat msgs, i have edited the post, hope it helps.

Comment: Clean and rebuild. Looks like your resource identifiers are not in sync between generated R.java and binary resource XML files.

Comment: @laalto Thanks a lot! Was struck for 2 hours! Clean and rebuild solved this. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean and rebuild your app.

Sometimes when editing resource XML files and reordering, adding or deleting elements with `@+id` identifiers the id numbers get messed up between generated `R.java` and compiled binary XML resource files. When requesting a view with `findViewById()`, the id matches some other view and attempting to cast the result to another type can cause a `ClassCastException`.

It's something Android developers using ADT have to learn: the build dependency system is not really reliable and when something related to resources doesn't quite work right, clean and rebuild first to see if it solves the issue.